# Deno HTTP Server not working on Deno Deploy with Oak

Tags: bcrypt, deno, oak, deno-deploy

Hi I'm having trouble deploying my Deno server to Deno Deploy.
I suppose it's having something to do with the Bcrypt library but I have no idea how I could fix this with maybe another library, or perhaps a deployment setting?

I'm using Oak as my middleware:

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v12.6.2/mod.ts";
import router from "./controllers/routes/routes.ts";

const app = new Application();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

console.log(`Application is listening on port: ${PORT}`);

await app.listen({ port: PORT });
```

For example this code has a signin functionality. The API works fine, but whenever it comes to the Bcrypt it gives an error "ReferenceWorker - Worker is not defined"
This is an example where I use the Bcrypt library:

```
import db from "./database/connectDB.ts";
import * as bcrypt from "https://deno.land/x/bcrypt@v0.4.1/mod.ts";
import { pbkdf2 } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.32.0/src/auth/pbkdf2.ts";
import { UserSchema } from "./schema/user.ts";
import { create, verify } from "https://deno.land/x/djwt@v3.0.1/mod.ts";
import { key } from "./utils/apiKey.ts";
import { passwordTest, validateEmail } from "./utils/filters.ts";

const users = db.collection<UserSchema>("users");

export const signin = async ({ req, res }: { req: any; res: any }) => {
  const body = await req.body();
  const { username, password } = await body.value;

  if (!username || !password) {
    res.status = 400;
    res.body = {
      message: `Please provide all required fields: username and password.`,
    };
    return;
  }

  const user = await users.findOne({ username });
  if (!user) {
    res.status = 404;
    res.body = {
      message: `Invalid credentials`,
    };
    return;
  }

  const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!passwordMatch) {
    res.status = 401;
    res.body = {
      message: "Invalid credentials",
    };
    return;
  }

  const payload = {
    id: user._id,
    username: user.username,
  };
  const jwt = await create({ alg: "HS512", typ: "JWT" }, { payload }, key);
  
  if (jwt) {
    res.status = 200;
    res.body = {
      message: "User logged in",
      data: {
        _id: user._id,
        token: jwt,
        username: user.username,
      },
    };
  } else {
    res.status = 500;
    res.body = {
      message: "Internal server error",
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Deno Deploy does not support the [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). Looking at bcrypt's [documentation](https://deno.land/x/bcrypt@v0.4.1#syncblocking) there are sync methods that don't use Web Workers.

Replacing `bcrypt.compare` with `bcrypt.compareSync` should work:

```
- const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
+ const passwordMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
```

Comment: This was indeed the answer! :)